# How can I correctly create the input files for DOS and Optical Properties of a supercell using Quantum ESPRESSO?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, density-of-states, self-consistent-field, supercell

I have a unit cell, and I want to create a 3x3x3 supercell.

Please, I need guidance on how to create properly the input files for Density of States (DOS) calculation (SCF and NSCF) and the input files for optical properties (SCF and Epsilon) using Quantum ESPRESSO. In fact,I want to avoid getting very intense peaks in the DOS calculation and minimize computational expenses for the optical properties calculations.

PS: I already tried to do that but it's not working properly.

Comment: Can you please include what did you try? The statement **PS: I already tried to do that but it's not working properly.** is not very helpful.